# Permission denied while enforcing python3 in mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

[image: A picture of my terminal]

I am trying to enforce python 3 on mac for installation of a firmware, it says permission denied. I have the script copied and pasted below.

```
Last login: Sat Mar 20 21:24:40 on ttys000
malharpatil@Malhars-MacBook-Air ~ % python --version
Python 2.7.16
malharpatil@Malhars-MacBook-Air ~ % ls -l /usr/local/bin/python*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  69 Mar 20 20:52 /usr/local/bin/python3 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  76 Mar 20 20:52 /usr/local/bin/python3-config -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3-config
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  71 Mar 20 20:52 /usr/local/bin/python3.9 -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  78 Mar 20 20:52 /usr/local/bin/python3.9-config -> ../../../Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/bin/python3.9-config
malharpatil@Malhars-MacBook-Air ~ % ln -s -f /usr/local/bin/python3.9 /usr/local/bin/python
ln: /usr/local/bin/python: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to execute this command as root. Put `sudo`  in front of your command, and it should work. You then have to enter your administrator password.